# Dealing with Very Large Satellite Imagery

Tags: python, gdal, large-datasets, maxar-digitalglobe

I'm curious if anyone has suggestions for viewing and processing really large imagery. I'm pretty experienced with desktop apps like ENVI and am comfortable with python and GDAL but I'm analyzing dozens and dozens (soon to be hundreds) of DigitalGlobe images that are around 40 gigs per file and I'm struggling to effectively do data exploration because it takes so long to even view them. And then I'm not sure what the best environment is to handle hundreds of images this size.

Does anyone know any cloud based viewers and analysis sandboxes that you recommend? I'm getting access to some beefy machines over the next week or two and I'd prefer to do it locally. Overall I just wanted to get an idea of suggested pipelines for analyzing this much imagery.

Comment: Don't expect *anything* over *the cloud* to be fast, work locally! What format is the raster currently in? **Have you built pyramids?** What software do you want to consume it in (yes, it makes a difference, different packages have different format support)? Are you using this data scene-by-scene or are you trying to use as a mosaic covering your area of interest?

Comment: Don't built pyramids with a very large Imagery !!! it will cause your  computer to freeze when you do that...

Comment: You have a point @PROBERT though the definition of *very large* is changing constantly; I recall when 4MB was considered large but recently I am using 300+GiB rasters and have worked with TiB+ sized rasters which built nicely. The process of building pyramids does depend on your software and settings though, using GDALADDO is reasonably quick even with rasters up to terrabyte size, Esri isn't too bad if you skip the first level though it would take about the same time to convert the format to ECW. Without pyramids I would not attempt to load these images into software like QGIS or ArcGIS.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I didn't realized his tag was about gdal so that might be different compare to ArcGIS ! so I was just suggesting...but I would be very interesting to know if gdal can handle that big.

Comment: You might want to consider loading them loading them into an array database like [rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.com/product.php)

Comment: The only thing you can do this is if you have the PhotoScan. I am taking this training tomorrow and I know I did some training in the past and this can allow you to export a very large imagery ...

Comment: Are you a Mac or unix user?

Comment: Do you have GBDX access?

Comment: @MichaelStimson this is more what I was talking about with on the cloud work: https://cloud.google.com/customers/planet/. That and EarthEngine type stuff.

I suppose "very large" in my application is ~50GiB per raster and right now around 20 files but it will soon be in the hundreds.

Comment: @nmtoken I'll look into Rasdaman, looks promising!

Comment: @phloem I hadn't heard of it but in many ways GBDX looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Not sure my researcher license to DG imagery will extend to GBDX but I'll look into it. Have you had any experience with it?

Comment: @clifgray I do have experience with it, and yes, it was built exactly for the type of massive scale processing you're trying to do. You set up workflows that fetch and process imagery in parallel without needing to actually download anything (output gets stored in s3 for you when you're ready). GDAL is available, plus many ENVI tasks. This all depends on access. Also, you pay per hour of compute, so that can add up. You might also be interested in DG's AnswerFactory, but I'm not as familiar with that.